# Make phpmailer() send a rich text or plain text email - not an html

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, plaintext, richtext

Im trying to send messages to a mail account that will only accept rich, or plain text emails. Im aware of the `AltBody` method, but i want to send the message primary as a rich or plain text email.

Ive looked through the docs but couldn't find an answer, does any one know how i can achieve this ?

Comment: You can to the point of specify which type of body your email will have, but you can't detect if the email account will only accept one or the other.

Comment: Thats fine, as i know which account the emails going to.. its our contact form being sent to us, so from that point of view its ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the HTML (rich) version to normal body and plaintext version to AltBody. Then send the mail as HTML. PhpMailer will send both bodies; clients capable of displaying HTML will display it, others should display plain text version.